# how can i put an image into select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-select

i have this script

```
<select>
<option value="1">one<img src="star.gif" height="15" width="15"></img> </option>
</select>
```

but it doesn't work.
how can i put an image into select?
thanks

### update:

so it's impossible?:(maybe via javascript?...

Comment: Nothing is impossible, just more difficult than it's worth.

Comment: yea, and how? i really need it:)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can't - DOM model doesn't allow img elements inside option elements

Answer (score 6):

Most website which associate images with a certain option in a menu use JavaScript or jQuery to change an image at the left or right of the menu whenever a new option is selected. However, it is not possible in any way to put an image inside or set a background image for an option element.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a menu list instead:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/44

Answer (score 0):

perhaps setting a background image with CSS - never done this so don't know if it works on not - I am guessing there will be browser issues with this too.

Comment: Option elements are too picky with styling, background images will not work. It's because an option element doesn't actually have background attributes, they have to follow the styles of the select element they fall under.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make this work cross-browser, as lots of browsers restrict what you can do with the  tag. FireFox browser is the only exception. But anyway, HTML tags inside options are not allowed [according to the standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html)