# Add icon inside dropdown menu list

Tags: html, css

How to Add icon inside DropDown Menu List.My Html Code is below.Please Help I want to Add edit icon and Delete Icon inside dropdown menu list
[Edit icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhgx0.png) [Delete Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fofKL.png)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Edit Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
Action: 
<select name="" id="">
<option value="">Select Action</option>
<option value="Edit">Edit</option>
<option value="Delete">Delete</option>
</select>
</br>
<input value="SAVE" type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Google is your friend. This has been asked many times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697996/image-in-select-element, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524953/how-can-i-put-an-image-into-select, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+select+image

Comment: You can't use those icons themselves... You can do something like this https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/OgEWyO will that work? If so I can reopen and submit as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with the option element. You will either have to create a list element from div's or you can use this library. Will solve your purpose.

I hope this helps.

https://tympanus.net/Development/SelectInspiration/index3.html