# React - image in <select>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I wanted to display some country list in React.js.

```
<select>
      <option><img src={require('../images/flags/en.png')} /> English</option>
</select>
```

Path and require are definitely correct, if I put that image outside of select - it displays **correctly**

Firstly, it displayed **[object Object] English** instead of displaying flag image. There was also an error in console: *index.js:1 Warning: Only strings and numbers are supported as  children*

I was looking for a solution using react-select but if it's achievable without that, I'd love to solve that using just plain   tags.

Comment: Which module bundler are you using? All depends on how you load your assets.

Comment: Are you sure that `require` is necessary? I would try to remove that and passing the image URL only. +1: add an `alt` attribute to `<img>` tag because if you miss that, it will cause warning.

Comment: @norbitrial Unfortunatelly, the problem stays the same.

Comment: Hi your answer is here, u cant add img tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524953/how-can-i-put-an-image-into-select.   U can achieve in different way like by jquery or  by <option style="background-image:url(en.png);">English</option> but you need to write css to arrange properly. I will recommend you to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select. with this package also you can achieve your output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i put an image into select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524953/how-can-i-put-an-image-into-select)

Comment: I've found another solution, react-flags-select. Thanks for your help guys, anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

`<option>` tag can only contain `Strings` and `Numbers` as 'Children Element'. In your case, you are trying to insert an `img` tag